# how to pass the value selected from a drop down list to a ruby on rails model

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am making a small website and i have a model called member and in it there a field called district 
`field :district, type: String`

in the view of the member there is a drop down list where i can choose the district i live in

`<select name="district">
    <option value="  " disabled selected>(please select a district)</option>
    <optgroup label="cairo">
    <option>Abdeen</option>
    <option>Ain Shams</option>
    </optgroup>
 </select>`

and everthing is working good but the problem is that i want to take the value which the user select from the drop down list and save it in the model field district

Answer (score 1):

you need to use form_for and write code in rails way

here is example:

```
<%= form_for @new_todo  do |f|  %>
    <%= f.select  :todo_item, @array_of_string_here %>
    <%= f.submit "Add todo", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <%end%>
```

Comment: could u please explain more . i am sorry i am a little bit new to ruby and html :D

Comment: go to this link, it will help you --> http://www.codelearn.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial/introducing-form_for

Comment: Also I think it should be `<%= f.select_tag :todo_item, options_for_select(@array_of_string_here) %>` because  `select` requires an `object`, a `method` and `choices`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a model for district as well. And make member model belong to district model. And use "collection_select" in form_for. The code will look like..

```
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>   
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :district %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:district_id, @districts, :id, :districst_name, {:prompt=>false}) %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

For more detail, see this [link](http://www.letmefix-it.com/2017/06/26/ruby-on-rails-drop-down-listcollection-select/).